# Remove icon for partially installed program on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, calibre

I attempted to install Calibre on Ubuntu 16.04, but the installation failed partway through. Following the installation instructions I was able to successfully complete the installation, but an icon with the interrupted installation process was left on the screen. I then completely uninstalled Calibre, but the icon is still there! How do I get rid of it?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: From user [Agterbosch](https://superuser.com/users/711877/agterbosch): Could be it's located in /usr/share/applications/theprogramname.desktop

Answer (score 0):

Could be it's located in /usr/share/applications/*theprogramname*.desktop

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and thanks for trying to help with this question. Just FYI, when you get a little more rep, a helpful, speculative suggestion like this would be better as a comment. Answer posts are intended for definitive solutions. I went ahead and copied this to a comment for you so it isn't lost if this gets deleted as a "non-answer".   The system put this in a [review queue](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/641029), so it will get some scrutiny. You might want to delete this yourself so it doesn't attract downvotes.  If the OP confirms it, post it again as an answer.